# How to run R scripts without closing X11

Tags: r

I would like to run an R script using a single command (e.g. bat file or shortcut).

This R script asks the user to choose a file and then plots information about that file. All is done via dialog boxes.

I don't want the user to go inside R - because they don't know it at all.

So, I was using r cmd and other similar stuffs, but as soon as the plots are displayed, R exits and closes the plots.

What can I do?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Several solutions are posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3301694/2954547

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220676/r-script-using-x11-window-only-opens-for-a-second) looks like a similar kind of a problem.

Solutions: (taken from above source)

1. Just sleep via  Sys.sleep(10) which would wait ten seconds.
2. Wait for user input via readLines(stdin()) or something like that [untested]
3. Use the tcltk package which comes with R and is available on all platforms to pop up a window the user has to click to make the click disappear. That solution has been posted a few times over the years on r-help.

2nd option is better to use for the user.

P.S. Since I did not come up with the answer myself, I tried to put it in comment but my reputation is too low for that.